Is it possible to separate parts into 3000 vertices a piece?
I am wondering if it's possible to separate a 80k vertices mesh into 3000 vertices a piece?  I am trying to separate a body of my car that has 80k vertices and split it all into 3000 vertices a piece. I am converting it for a game and the game has a limit of 3k vertices per piece. I'm new to blender and love learning new technique to make things go quicker and easier. I am also not sure if I'm asking the question right either.


you can try with the remesh tools of Blender, or use an external tool like Instant Meshes or Quad Remesher? The result may not be very good though in terms of topology and deformation

I'll give it a try, and thank you for replying back with me!
